# Can an encrypted zip-file also protect it's internal directory

Tags: c#, encryption, zip, dotnetzip

I'm creating an encrypted zip file using DotNetZip using WinZip AES 256. However I'm able to read the directory and even to remove some of the zipentries without having the encryption key.

As far as I understand the directory visibility is a limitation of the Zip format. I just wonder, if this also applies for any changes in removing / adding components to the zip file or does there exist a way for preventing such changes.

EDIT:

A quick read of [Zip File Format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_%28file_format%29) seems to show, that double zipping seems to be the only solution to prevent random removal / addition of comoponents in a zipfile, regardless of encryption of the single entry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the kb of the [Winzip](http://kb.winzip.com/kb/entry/147/) last update last updated `20 Feb, 2013`:

> To hide the names of the files in your encrypted Zip file, you can double zip them. To do this:

So I'll say no :-)

`Winrar` has an option to encrypt the filenames, sadly the algorithm isn't public.